# htaccess rewrite multiple conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I don´t know how to solve this problem. I need to redirect from http to https but only in some cases:

**Redirect**

```
http://example.com to https://example.com
http://example.com/any-url to https://example.com/any-url
```

**Don´t redirect**

```
http://subdomain1.example.com
http://subdomain2.example.com
http://example.com/any-file.xml
```

Im turning on ssl but only my domain has a certification, and i like to keep xml files without redirection to avoid some partners issues.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this would work, assuming your regular HTTP connection is port 80:

```
# If the site is plain HTTP
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
# and if the requested filename is not an XML file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*)\.xml$
# and if the URL specifies the request is for the primary domain (not subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
# then rewrite to HTTPS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You would need to of course insert the correct domains, but it should work. I tested it on my system and it did.